# Cannot connect to ec2 jasperserver after changing postgresql.conf file

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jasperserver

Problem :I am using bundled Amazon Web Service (LINUX) ec2 integrated with jaspersoft server, I want to push some pdf documents to the server's db(postgresql).
Hence i need to access PostgreSQL of jasper server from local machine to push the pdfs daily to server,

Comment: i have added my method just to submit the post, regret for un-necessary words in between :(

Answer (score 0):

postgresql service got stopped due to the changes in the postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf files and the permissions on these files should not be given to any other users apart from postgres.

changing the permissions set the service up and postgres started and jasperserver either..